# Persist values after reload react-hook-form

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form

I have a Form with several components:

```
return (
    <>
      <FormProvider {...methods} >
        <div className="mt-12">
          <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)} action="#" method="POST" >
            <Email/>
            <Personal/>
            <h2 className='font-semibold text-xl'>Geburtsdaten</h2>
            <p className='mb-5 text-gray-400 text-sm'>Du musst mindestens 18 Jahre alt sein, um online einen Vertrag abzuschließen.</p>
            <div className="sm:col-span-2 grid grid-cols-3 gap-4 mb-5">
              <div className="mt-1">
                < SelectBirthYear
                  years={years}
                  value={selectedYear}
                  onChange={setSelectedYear}/>
              </div>
              <div className="mt-1">
                < SelectBirthMonth 
                  startYear={startYear}
                  selectedYear={selectedYear}
                  months={months}
                  value={selectedMonth}
                  reducedMonths={reducedMonths}
                  onChange={monthSelect}/>
              </div>
              <div className="mt-1">
                <SelectBirthDay
                  startYear={startYear}
                  selectedYear={selectedYear}
                  selectedMonth={selectedMonth}
                  monthNow={monthNow}
                  days={days}
                  value={selectedDay}
                  reducedDays={reducedDays}
                  onChange={daySelect}
                />
              </div>
            </div>
            <Contact/>
            <BankDetails/>
            <Checkboxes />
            <div className="sm:col-span-2">
            </div>
            <div className="mt-5 sm:mt-8 sm:flex sm:justify-center lg:justify-center">
              <div className="rounded-md shadow">
                <a role="button" tabIndex={0}
                  onClick={prevFormStep}
                  className="w-full flex items-center justify-center px-8 py-3 border border-transparent text-base font-medium rounded-md text-white bg-yellow-500 hover:bg-yallow-600 md:py-4 md:text-lg md:px-10"
                >
                  Zurück
                </a>
              </div>
              <div className="mt-3 sm:mt-0 sm:ml-3">
                <input
                  type='submit'
                  value='Vertrag abschließen'
                  className="w-full flex items-center justify-center px-8 py-3 border border-transparent text-base font-medium rounded-md text-white bg-yellow-500 hover:bg-yallow-600 md:py-4 md:text-lg md:px-10"
                />
              </div>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
        
      </FormProvider>
    </>
  )
```

For my From validations I already use react-hook-form:

```
 const methods = useForm({ mode: 'onTouched' });
 const { handleSubmit } = methods;
```

So now, looking into documentation, I can't see the possibility of persisting values on input change. In the console I can access the _formValues in the control, but in my App I can't even manage to console.log those. Also, about control it is said: This object contains methods for registering components into React Hook Form. Important: do not access any of the properties inside this object directly. It's for internal usage only.

My thinking was, if I can access the formValues, then I could save those into Local Storage. But I am not getting that far. Also, having form with a lot of components, naming each where I wish to save the Value on every change woudn't be dry. So is there any strategy to get all values out of my Form and to add those to local storage, so if for whatever reason User reloads or goes back in the browser history, the filles out form persists?

Comment: It might be easier to try something like Formik, where you have more access to the state of the form, and where you can hook in the Yup validation framework too.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't change that anymore. Also, for learning purpouses it would be greta to figure it out. I am also using context, where I could somehow set values as the data. Just need to access those ...

Answer (score 0):

If it's okay to keep all form fields in one object, then you can use useFormPersist and put control to all form fileds.  It will watch every changes and save values in real-time to localStorage. `useFormPersist("nameOfYourStorage", { watch, setValue, storage: window.localStorage, });`
and do not forget install dependecies.

> npm i react-hook-form-persist